# Scrapy Crawler:Avoid Duplicate Crawling of URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a crawler using Scrapy.The crawler is crawling the website fetching the URL.
Technology Used:Python Scrapy
Issue:I am having duplication of URLs.
What I need the output to be:
I want the crawler to crawl the website and fetch the URL's but not crawl the duplicate URL's.
Sample Code:
I have added this code to my settings.py file.
DUPEFILTER_CLASS ='scrapy.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter'
I ran the file its says module not found.

```js
import scrapy
import os
import scrapy.dupefilters
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    # this is equivalent to what you would set in settings.py file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'inputLinks2.csv'
    }
    filePath='inputLinks2.csv'
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
     os.remove(filePath)
    else:
     print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")
    start_urls = ['https://www.mytravelexp.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for  title in titles:
            yield {'title': title}
            

    def __getid(self, url):
        mm = url.split("&refer")[0] #or something like that
        return mm

    def request_seen(self, request):
        fp = self.__getid(request.url)
        if fp in self.fingerprints:
            return True
        self.fingerprints.add(fp)
        if self.file:
            self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy filters duplicate requests by default.